# How do I make an iframe show at 100%?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, iframe, webview2

I am trying to follow along with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68670051/set-webview2-source-directly-to-a-binary-stream/68671066#68671066) to show a PDF in a WebView2.
I have set my WebView2 to dockstill "Fill", so it will use the entire space of the form.

The author recommends:

```
Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div>" &
        $"<iframe width=100% height=500 src=""data:Application/pdf;base64,{pdfBase64}"">" &
        "</iframe></div></body></html>"

Me.WebView2.NavigateToString(html)
```

This works.

The PDF is displayed over the width of the webview / form and with 500 pixels in height.

However, I would like the iframe to be the size of the parent.
To do that, I change "500" to "100%" like this:

```
Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div>" &
        $"<iframe width=100% height=100% src=""data:Application/pdf;base64,{pdfBase64}"">" &
        "</iframe></div></body></html>"
```

This has no effect. Instead, the pdf that is shown in the iframe gets a height of 152 pixels.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KJ Wow, why is that so, and how could I achieve what I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably just invalid or at least not well-formatted `HTML` string. I'd suggest using the `XElement` syntax to build the `HTML` output, it helps to write the tags and attributes correctly...

```vb
Dim pdfBytes = 'The PDF byte array...
Dim pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes)
Dim html =
    <html>
        <body>
            <iframe
                width="100%"
                height="100%"
                src=<%= $"data:application/pdf;base64,{pdfBase64}" %>>
            </iframe>
        </body>
    </html>.ToString()

WebView21.NavigateToString(html)
```

[image: SO73708467]

Nice `VB.NET` feature.

Answer (score 0):

can you try height="auto"; what is your parent div's height?

```
html<iframe src="/default.asp" width="100%" height="auto" style="border:1px solid black;"> </iframe>
```

Comment: You can provide with a clear example with code format. For example: 
```html<iframe src="/default.asp" width="100%" height="auto" style="border:1px solid black;">
</iframe>
````

Answer (score 0):

iframe height only allows height=pixels so 100%=minimum (default=150)

see [HTML5 iFrame is only 150px in height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961142/html5-iframe-is-only-150px-in-height)

there are many workarounds to try to hold the frame via other settings and a good suggested method is by @Alohci https://stackoverflow.com/a/24964263/10802527

result see the sidebar

[image]

For simplicity of a single frame try

```
<style>
html, body, iframe { border: none; height: 98%; }
</style>
```

[image]

**But simplest is decide a desired height.**
Workarounds may not work well based on user settings
[image]